# subtract 2 column and echo out rows only higher than zero

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with that as topic said.
Lets say i have table with 3 column.

```
materials | total amount | amount
==================================
mouse     | 5            | 2
keyboard  | 10           | 5
phone     | 5            | 5
```

im showing this table with this code.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM materials");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo  $row['materials'] 
  echo  $row['total_amount']
}
```

Now i want to show this table like this.

```
materials | total amount 
========================
mouse     | 3           
keyboard  | 5
```

How to archive it please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"SELECT `materials`,(`total_amount` - `amount`) AS `newAmount` FROM `materials` WHERE (`total_amount` - `amount`) > 0;"
```

Comment: how come alias is accessible in the `where` clause?

Comment: Because this is a new virtual col created while selecting cols: `(total_amount - amount) AS newAmount`

Comment: @491243 I can see that you are not a newb, and it looks like you are a professional SQL programmer!!, are you wondering because it's wrong or just asking to get more details??!!

Comment: I was wondering why it is working. As we know, the [**order of sql operation**](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm) executed in the server is `FROM => WHERE => GROUP BY => HAVING => SELECT....`. and your **query failed** when tested at `MySQL 5.5.32` [See Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4c8b/5)

Comment: o.O it's working my localhost (5.6.12-log) but not working on sqlfiddle (MySQL 5.6.6 m9), actually he can replace `newAmount > 0` with `(total_amount - amount) > 0`

Comment: and thank you for noticing even thought i didn't new it can't be done with previous versions, but this is a new block in my knowledge castle *_-

Answer (score 3):

subtract `amount` from `total amount`

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE `total amount` - amount > 0
```